# Python Username Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following is my code:

```
string1 = (input("What is your name?")) #creates a string, stores the name in it
first1 = string1[:1]

string2 = (input("What is your last name?"))
first3 = string2[:3]

from random import randint
sentence = "".join((str(randint(0,9)), first1.lower(), first3.upper()))
print (sentence)
sentence = "".join((str(randint(0,9)), first1.lower(), first3.upper()))
print (sentence)
```

It works, but I am having some trouble. I need to loop this 5 times - but it doesn't work for some reason!

P.S. Python 3!

Comment: What error and how are you trying to loop?

Comment: Why do you crate a tuple of tuples instead of a string (`sentence = (randint(0,9),(first1.lower()),(first3.upper()))`)?

Comment: I used "for i in range [5]:" not sure why it isn't working...

Comment: How would we create a string with those? Sorry - new to python!

Comment: @linusg It's not a tuple of tuples, just a tuple. But still, that explains the "spaces" in the output.

Comment: `range[5]` tries to get the subscription 5 from `range`. You should call it, like `range(5)`.

Comment: when i use for i in range, it makes my string1 an error... @ilja-everilä

Comment: @tobias_k `(..., (...), (...))` this should be a tuple without tuples in it??

Comment: Please include the whole looping construct you are trying to use in your post.

Comment: @linusg `(x)` is just the same as `x`; to make it a tuple, it would have to be `(x,)`

Comment: @tobias_k how would i get rid of the "tuples" - i don't know how to make it into a string so that it becomes an actual user name..

Comment: @IljaEverilä   for i in range(5):
string1 = (input("What is your name?")) 
first1 = string1[:1]


string2 = (input("What is your last name?"))
first3 = string2[:3]


from random import randint
sentence = (randint(0,9),(first1.lower()),(first3.upper()))

Comment: Please edit your post and include it there, so it'll be easier for others to find too. It'll help you get better answers now and in the future. You also shouldn't edit answers in to your post, as it'll confuse those reading your question later.

Comment: @tobias_k        FN = (input("What is your name?")) is this a string?

Comment: @IljaEverilä would u classify this a string? firstletter = FN[:1]

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a `tuple` called sentence, rather than a `string`

If you change that line to this:

```
sentence = "".join((str(randint(0,9)), first1.lower(), first3.upper()))
```

It will create a string that has no gaps, like so when printed:

```
What is your name?First
What is your last name?Last
5fLAS
```

Comment: ... or just use `... + ... + ...` to join.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list, not a string so it seems logical that you get issues when trying to print it...

To append to a string you can do that :

```
sentence = str(randint(0,9))+(first1.lower())+(first3.upper())
```

In Python, you don't give a type to your variables, it depends of what you put INTO them.
In Python, elements between parenthesis "()" are considered as TUPLE (a type similar to a list, but that cant be modified), "[]" stands for a list, "{}" stands for a dictionnary. So you must **NOT put parts of a string between parenthesis and separated with commas or you will turn them into a list of words**. Instead you can use "+" that means to Python that you are making a **string concatenation**. Also note that i casted your random number into string. If you give 3 strings separated by "+" Python will automatically detect sentence as a String. Wp you've created a string !

If you have a list and want to get rid of the spaces you can also use :

```
"".join(yourlist)
```

However i don't recommend it here, you would be creating a list and using a join for nothing since you can create a string from the begining.

Edit: As for the loop, we can't answer if you don't copy paste the code of the loop and the error, it could be a million things.

Comment: Thankyou! How could I make this into a string rather than a list ? is there any possible way ?

Comment: Hello. No problem. The solution i gave you IS a string. I added more details so you may understand the difference. Let me know if you don't get it.